# Magento Admin : Configure product not display properly in Admin -> Mange Product

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.1 and if i am goint to edit configure product or add configure product than tab are not display properly and its working for the simple product. Its very strange to me.

I also try to replace default magento files but still getting same error. I am replaced adminhtml/catalog and mage/catalog but still issue was there.

I also disabled all the extension but not getting success.

I try to get error and i found that in firebug like below

```
<a id="product_info_tabs_configurable" class="tab-item-link ajax" title="Associated Products" name="configurable" href="#">
<span>
<span class="changed" title="The information in this tab has been changed."></span>
<span class="error" title="This tab contains invalid data. Please solve the problem before saving."></span>
Associated Products
</span>
</a>
```

and below of the my screenshot of the admin panel manage product and i am trying to edit configure product and also same error in the create new configure product.

[image]

Please help me out from the this problem.

Comment: The page is not rendering completely. If you take a look in the source of the page you will see that is not ending with `</html>`. If you turn on error reporting and developer mode you should see the error message in the page source. Something like `Fatal Error:...`

Comment: @Marius because of the tag completion issue i put default magento files of the catalog in adminhtml but not getting success.

Comment: First try to identify the problem then solve it. edit `index.php` and uncomment the line `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and change `if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}` to `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);`. Then try again. It will show you the error message in the page source. Add it to your question.

Comment: @Marius Thanks for your help i got `Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object` this error

Comment: Hmmm...I wasn't expecting that. That may be caused by one of your extensions. Try to disable them one by one and see if the error reproduces.

Comment: @Marius Yesterday i am disabled all the extension but let me check it once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this problem by replace `catalog` folder of  `\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\`

I have replace admin folder but it's not working for me. So please try frontend folder i think it works for you also.

I posted this answer because it helps someone.